# How to get the parameters(like Width and Height) of a view of an fragment to a Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I'm beginner to android and currently I'm working on a small project.
In my project I have a fragment with text and imageview, and in my Main activity I have a button and imageview.
When I press the button in my activity class it opens up the fragment, but I want to animate(Move) the the imageview in main activity to the position of the imageview present in the fragment.

Is there any simple way of getting the position of the views present in the fragments to activity class?

I'm stuck in this situation from few hours. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are attempting is difficult because that is not how you are supposed to do it. `Fragments` are supposed to be self contained units, completely modular and interchangeable. On the other hand `Activities` are just supposed to be empty containers for `Fragments`. All the logic and UI has to be contained in the `Fragments` them selves and the `Activities` are supposed to be used to arrange and display those `Fragments`. Nothing from outside a `Fragment` should have anything to do with something inside the `Fragment`. So if you restructure your app with that in mind you will find that everything will be **MUCH** simpler.

A few pointers:

- Move all of the UI to the `Fragment`
- It is completely fine to perform `FragmentTransactions` from inside a `Fragment`. You don't have to take a detour through the `Activity`.
- Try to understand the difference between `Fragments` and `Activities` and don't let yourself be mislead by tutorials which don't adhere to this separation. Most Android tutorials on the internet are outdated and wrong. Refer to the official tutorials [**here**](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your time and response,and it was really helpful. I'll try to implement my view objects in fragments and keep my activity empty..